# Why importing separate nav component with link react-router doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom for my navigation and routing.
I'm wondering why the `Link` doesn't work when separating the Nav from the main App.

**Nav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu, Layout } from 'antd';
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const { Sider } = Layout;

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Sider
        breakpoint="lg"
        collapsedWidth="0"
        onBreakpoint={(broken) => { console.log(broken); }}
        onCollapse={(collapsed, type) => { console.log(collapsed, type); }}
      >
        <div className="logo" />
        <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <Link to="/account">
                <div>Account</div>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Link to="/feed">
                <div>Feed</div>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </Sider>
    )
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import Nav from './Nav';
import PageFooter from './PageFooter';
import Account from './Account';
import Feed from './Feed';

const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
          <Nav/>
          <Layout>
            <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px', padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 280 }}>
              <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
              <Route exact path="/feed" component={Feed} />
            </Content>
            <PageFooter/>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Doing this, the `Links` in the `Nav.js` don't work.
However if I should paste the code from `Nav.js` directly to `App.js` it works perfectly fine.

I've also tried changing my `Nav.js` to a function only component. Still I'm getting the same result.

Comment: `import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom'` is not correct. Just import `Link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your import is not correct 
you should

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

in nav.js also it is better to use Switch => 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch